# Triggers in PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables:

```
create table speciality(
major          varchar2(30),
total_credits  number,
total_students number);

create table students(
id              number(5) primary key,
first_name      varchar2(20),
last_name       varchar2(20),
major           varchar2(30),
current_credits number(3));
```

I want to create a trigger that carries the name `UpdateSpeciality` that deletes, updates and inserts into `speciality` table right when the same operation happens on `students` table.

This is how the `speciality` table should look after the following:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO STUDENTS(id, first_name, last_name, major, current_credits) values(10001, 'sam', 'ali', 'computer science', 11);

SQL>INSERT INTO STUDENTS(id, first_name, last_name, major, current_credits) values(10002, 'kevin', 'mark', 'MIS', 4);

SQL>INSERT INTO STUDENTS(id, first_name, last_name, major, current_credits) values(10003, 'robert', 'jack', 'computer science', 8);
```

How can I solve this? I don't know how to connect the two tables.

Should I use stored procedures?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UpdateSpeciality
after insert or delete or update on students
for each row
begin
if inserting /* this is how far i got */
```

Comment: PL-SQL is the sql dialect used by Oracle. It is (often very) different from TSQL used by sql server.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL server?

Comment: The specialty table appears to be a summary by major and as such seems pointless since you could simply run a query to get the summary or possibly create a view to do the same.

Comment: @P.Salmon - of course you're right, nobody should do this in real life. But we find questions on this site with a table called STUDENTS are almost always homework. And the fact is, college assignments often present unrealistic scenarios, because the course needs to cover the whole PL/SQL arsenal, not just the parts we actually use in the day job.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah you're right, it's oracle , thanks

Comment: @Amit Kumar i'm using oracle

Comment: @APC i know it's pointless but just like what P.Salmon said, it's a college assignment, and this question came in the final exam last semester. So...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. With some assumtions :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UpdateSpeciality
after insert or delete or update on students
for each row
declare
   cursor c_spec(sMajor speciality.major%type) is
   select * from speciality
   where major = sMajor
   for update;
   r_spec c_spec%ROWTYPE;
begin
if inserting then
    open c_spec(:new.major);
    fetch c_spec into r_spec;
    if c_spec%FOUND then
        update speciality set
          total_credits = total_credits + :new.current_credits,
          total_students = total_students + 1
        where current of c_spec; 
    else
        insert into speciality(major, total_credits, total_students) values (:new.major, :new.current_credits, 1);
    end if;
    close c_spec;
elsif updating then
    open c_spec(:new.major);
    fetch c_spec into r_spec;
    if c_spec%FOUND then
        update speciality set
          total_credits = total_credits + :new.current_credits - :old.current_credits
        where current of c_spec;     
    else
        insert into speciality(major, total_credits, total_students) values (:new.major, :new.current_credits, 1);    
    end if;
    close c_spec;
elsif deleting then
    open c_spec(:old.major);
    fetch c_spec into r_spec;
    if c_spec%FOUND then
        update speciality set
          total_credits = total_credits - :old.current_credits ,
          total_students = total_students - 1
        where current of c_spec;         

        if r_spec.total_students = 1 then
            delete from speciality where major = :old.major;
        end if;
    end if;
    close c_spec;
end if;
end;
```